# VS Code freezing after latest update

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, redhat

I am using VS code on Red Hat Linux and it is freezing after opening. The only option I have is to forcefully quit. It was working fine until last week. I was told by the admin that this problem was caused due to a recent update. What can I do?

Comment: As of I think version 1.53, RHEL 7 is no longer supported, this was my issue - perhaps yours is the same? https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53#_electron-11-update

Comment: I have a similar issue since some time with Flatpak (Fedora).
What is interesting, it freezes only when starting from the UI (clicking on the Icon).
When staring it from the command line it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flatpak release which is stable and provides security features, runtimes, sandboxing.

for installing flatpak `sudo yum install flatpak`

and

```
flatpak install flathub com.visualstudio.code
```